# Getting out of EFI Shell version 2.70

Tags: efi

I bought an Acer Nitro 5, and I'm stuck in the EFI Shell version 2.70 screen.
As a not-tech guy, I have no idea what to do from here.
I've been Googling to find an answer, but it just doesn't seem to be working.
So far, I have set a supervisor password, and that's it.
I've tried typing exit and then enter, but that leads me to a Boot Manager screen, with UEFI_SHELL as the only Boot option menu.
Thank you so much for reading, and I hope to hear from you tech people soon.

Answer (score 2):

Typing `exit` then <kbd>Enter</kbd> will leave the current EFI shell.

As described in the [UEFI Shell specification](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Shell_2_2.pdf), the `exit` command...

> Exits the UEFI Shell environment and returns
> control to the parent that launched the UEFI
> Shell.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking the wrong question. You should rather ask:

> Why do I get the EFI shell instead of Windows?

And the answer is: **There is no operating system (Windows or not) on this computer.**

Inspect the laptop for a Windows logo sticker. There's probably none - it comes without a Windows license. You have to buy Windows separately and install it.

If there's a Windows sticker, you can prepare a Windows installation drive on any USB flash drive and install Windows. It will automatically pick up the license from the motherboard.