# How do I change the boot order via EFI shell version 2.70 of an Intel® Celeron® Processor N4000?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, intel

How do I change the boot order via EFI shell version 2.70 of an Intel® Celeron® Processor N4000?

This response doesn't solve the issue: https://superuser.com/a/1596787/626570. Meaning, I can exit EFI and when I do so I am brought to the correct distro.

I am using this NUC with Ubuntu Core, for a production IoT project, therefore, Ubuntu Core needs to load at power up, not EFI.

I am unable to find an updated version of this Intel document: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/server/sb/efi_instructions.pdf. I am unsure if it is the latest. As when I type `bcfg` I get the following error:

`'bcfg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file`

I was able to use the document to go through the directory, find EFI, and boot Ubuntu core, but again, this device will be used in a production environment. Therefore this is not acceptable.

Lastly, I have tried pressing F2 or F6, or F10 at boot before hitting the EFI screen and that didn't work either.

I have tried Googling to find the "latest" Intel pdf with no luck.

Additional context: NUC came with Windows, and I successfully was able to replace it with the Ubuntu server. Then decided I rather use Ubuntu Core. From the Ubuntu server, I installed Ubuntu Desktop and changed the boot order to load Ubuntu Core (ubuntu-core-22-amd64.img.xz) from USB.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/install-nuc

Comment: @ChanganAuto that does not address the question.

Comment: I can suggest an edit but will you accept it?

Comment: BTW, I've already corrected your answer. I hope is to your liking and if so please accept the edit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rather than change the boot order from the UEFI shell. Pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> at boot opened the firmware (UEFI) settings where I changed the boot order.

Answer (score 2):

Note that 2.70 is probably the *version of the main UEFI specification* implemented by the firmware, not the *version of the shell*. As far as I know, there is no version 2.70 of the UEFI shell in existence yet... the latest release would be *UEFI Shell v2.2, release 22H2*.

You already found your answer, but let me suggest some alternatives:

- If you need specifically to edit the boot settings *within the UEFI shell* (e.g. if you want to use a `.nsh` script to automate something at the firmware level), you could supply an updated version of `shell.efi` to the ESP and run that. The updated `shell.efi` would then allow you to use the `bcfg` command. Unfortunately the TianoCore project seems to release source code versions only, but https://github.com/pbatard/UEFI-Shell provides the shells as pre-built `.EFI` files (go to Releases, then extract the `\efi\boot\bootx64.efi` from the newest available ISO image: that's your updated shell).
- If you can boot the system to Linux even once in UEFI mode, there should be an `efibootmgr` command you can use to manipulate firmware-level boot settings. If you have a stripped-down installation for IoT, you might have to add the `efibootmgr` package first.

Comment: Thank you this is helpful and bookmarked it.